# Transparent PNG as background for ul is only transparent when ul is positioned absolutely

Tags: html, css

I encountered a strange problem where I had an unordered list with a background image of a partially transparent PNG. The transparency was not showing until I set the position of the unordered list as absolute. Is there any explanation for this? It's really throwing me off.

```
<ul id="flag_down">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="flag" onclick="return false"></a><span>Flag</span>
                        <ul id="fd-menu">
                            <li><a class="js-inpost-duplicate" href="#duplicate">duplicate</a></li>
                            <li><a class="js-inpost-nsfw" rel="83858" href="#nsfw">nsfw</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/dmca/">copyright</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

The CSS:

```
#flag_down li ul {
display:none;
left:6px;
margin-top:2px;
position:relative;
background: url("../bg-dropdown.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent;
width: 83px;
z-index: 9999;
```

}

Comment: Which browser does this happen on? Can you post the code where you place the background image? (and perhaps a bit of the parent elements).

Comment: Sorry, should've specified. The browser is Safari.

Comment: You do realize that you are not displaying the list at all with `display:none;`

Comment: Also, I tried this in my version of Safari and it worked fine...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kue4C/2/ Still works

Answer (score -1):

Use JavaScript:

```
var uls = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
for(var i=0; i<uis.length; i++) {
     var t = uis[i];
     if(t.style.position == "absolute") 
         t.setAttribute("style", 'url("../bg-dropdown.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent;'); 
}
```